# External JavaScript function editing HTML list title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

All,

I am making a login page. Upon successful login, the username of the logged in user should display at the top of the screen. Upon clicking the username, a dropdown list should appear.

So I have an HTML script that will creates an un-ordered list. I want to make a call to an external javaScript function within the HTML. I want this function to edit the title of the un-ordered list with custom input handled in the javascript function, and make the list visible, as it is not displayed by default. How do I edit this script so I can call the function to create a custom title for my un-ordered list?

Javascript

```
function successfulLogin() { 
    $("#UserDropdown").show();
    document.getElementById("loginMenu").innerHTML = "my stuff";

}
```

HTML

```
<script src="~\Scripts\successfulLogin.js" style="display: none"></script>

<div id="dropboxbackground">
<div>
<ul id="dropdown">
    <li>
        <a id="loginMenu" href="#">title</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<header>
    <div id="headerBar"></div>
</header>
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing JQuery with DOM manipulation? Why not just stick with JQuery?

Comment: I'm not confident in JQuery either.

Comment: @user1917026 `document.getElementById("loginMenu").innerHTML = "my stuff";` would be `$("#loginMenu").html("my stuff");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a label inside the anchor tag and upon clicking the username call the **successfulLogin** javascript method  using href=**'javascript:successfulLogin()'** or depending upon the type of control you have used for displaying the username.

```
<script src="~\Scripts\successfulLogin.js" style="display: none"></script>
<div>
<ul id="dropdown">
<li>
    <a id="loginMenu" href='#'><label id="lbl"> title
     </label></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Account Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And Write your javascript(jquery) as :  This would change the title of the ordered list to "somestuff"

```
function successfulLogin() { 
$("#UserDropdown").show();
$('#lbl').text("somestuff");

 }
```